# Exibir div em baixo de div no mobile

Tags: html5, css3

Sou iniciante no **CSS**, tenho `divs` de duas e três colunas que ficam bem ajustadas quando exibidas no *PC*, porém preciso modificar o comportamento delas quando visulizadas no *mobile*. Gostaria que as `divs` ficassem uma embaixo da outra mas não estou conseguindo.

Abaixo segue meu código, o **CSS** está `inline` porque estou usando dentro do *Wordpress*.

```css
<div id="site" style="width:100%; margin-top:0; margin-left:auto; margin-bottom:0; margin-right:auto; background-color:#666;">

 <div id="header" style="width:100%; background-color:#ffffff;">

 <div id="conteudo" style="width:100%;height:400px; background-color:#0F0">
 
  <div id="conteudo-left" style="width:50%; float:left; background-color:#fff; ">
  <center><a href="https://www.igrejanet.webpress.net.br/tutorial/" target="_blank"><img style="width: 100%; max-width: 450px; padding: 15px;" src="https://www.webpress.net.br/img/tutoriais.jpg"></a><br>
  <center><h3><span style="color: #0091d5;">APRENDA FÁCIL</span><h3>
  <p style="padding: 5px 25px 25px 25px; color: black;"> A<span style="text-transform: lowercase;">cesse nossos tutoriais de ajuda e saiba como editar seu site e
  usar seu painel Administrativo, com dicas de edição ilustradas passo a passo.</span></p>
  <h5><a href="https://www.igrejanet.webpress.net.br/tutorial/" target="_blank"><img style="width: 100%; max-width: 150px; " src="https://www.webpress.net.br/img/clique-aqui.jpg"></h5></a>
  </center>
  </center></div>
  
  <div id="conteudo-right" style="width:50%;  float:left; background-color:#fff;">
  <center><a href="https://www.webpress.net.br/central" target="_blank"><img style="width: 100%; max-width: 450px; padding: 15px;" src="https://www.webpress.net.br/img/mensalidade.jpg"></a><br>
  <center><h3><span style="color: #0091d5 ;">CENTRAL DE PAGAMENTOS</span><h3>
  <p style="padding: 5px 25px 25px 25px; color: #000000;"> É <span style="text-transform: lowercase;">muito fácil pagar sua mensalidade, basta acessar nossa central de pagamentos
  e pagar via boleto ou cartão de crédito agora mesmo.</span></p>
  <h5><a href="https://www.webpress.net.br/central" target="_blank""><img style="width: 100%; max-width: 150px; " src="https://www.webpress.net.br/img/clique-aqui.jpg"></h5></a>
  </center>
  </center></div>

 </div>
 <div id="servicos" style="width:100%; background-color:#fff;">  
  <div id="servicos-dois" style="display: inline-block; width: 33%; background-color:#fff;">
   <center><img style="width: 100%; max-width: 100px;" src="https://www.webpress.net.br/img/icone-servicos.png">
   <h2 style="color: #0091d5;">Suporte</h2><br><br>
   <p>Precisando de suporte acesse a página abaixo</p>
   <p><a href="https://www.webpress.net.br/suporte/" target="_blank">http://www.webpress.net.br/suporte/</a></p>
   </center>
  </div>
  <div id="servicos-um" style="float: left; width: 33%; background-color:#fff;">
   <center><img style="width: 100%; max-width: 100px;" src="https://www.webpress.net.br/img/icone-atendimento.png">
   <h2 style="color: #0091d5;">Atendimento</h2><br><br>
   <p>WhatsApp: (51)992475352</p><p>E-mail: contato@webpress.net.br</p>
   </center>
  </div>
  <div id="servicos-tres" style="float: right; width: 33%; background-color:#fff;">
   <center><img style="width: 100%; max-width: 100px;" src="https://www.webpress.net.br/img/icone-horario.png">
   <h2 style="color: #0091d5;">Horário</h2><br><br>
   <p>Segunda a sexta</p>8 às 12h - 14 às 18h
   </center>
  </div>
 </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Tem como incluir o CSS na pergunta?

Comment: Goveia já vou te falar de cara, usando estilos "inline" vc não vai conseguir! Simplesmente pq vc não vai conseguir construir seus breaking points `@media` direto no estilo da tag. Além disso por hierarquia do CSS os estilos direto na tag tem maior peso do que o que é escrito em um arquivo .css por exemplo, então mesmo usando um CSS externo vc não vai conseguir sobrescrever o estilo que já está na tag. Resumindo se vc não tirar os estilos de dentro da tag vc não vai conseguir fazer um site responsivo.

Comment: @dvd ou então sapecando um !important em 100% das classes rss... melhor nem dar ideia né :D

Comment: Poxa tive que procurar "pogar" no google, mas é dai pra pior haha

Comment: @dvd esses problemas de crossbrowser com Safari pra mim é complicado pq não trabalho no Mac so Windows, e a última versão do Safari pra Windows acho que é de 2012... Mas posta ai que eu tento te dar uma força sim. Se o loader que vc usou foi exatamente aquele já tente trocar o `rotate()` por `rotateZ()` para testar, ele é acelerado por hardware, as vezes da certo vai saber, pq as classes eu já vi que usam -webkit-. Se quiser postar a pergunta ajudo no que puder. Valeu o elogia, mas tu que é o metre aqui! :p

Comment: @dvd o nome da animação tb tem que ter o prefixo -webkit-animation:nome sasporra de prefixo enche o saco...

Answer (score 0):

Da uma olhada no bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/
Com ele da pra fazer isso de forma simples.

Só incluir na página o arquivo bootstrap.css.
Essa tag no head:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

E nas divs usar as classes correspondentes, no caso pra o mobile seria col-sm-12 e col-md-4
No site do bootstrap explica bem direitinho

Comment: Obrigado vou tentar usar o Bootstrap então.